# OpenRasta Mocking HttpContext in Unit Tests

Tags: c#, nunit, openrasta

Currently i am writing a unit tests for my handler methods using **NUnit**.I have used `HttpContext.Current` in one of my Controller Methods which throws NULL reference exception at `HttpContext.Current` when i execute test cases for my handler.

Is there any way i can mock **HttpContext**?or is there any other way to solve this issue.

Comment: Why do you need to access HttpContext.Current directly? OpenRasta provides abstractions over most things so you should be able to take one of its interfaces as a dependency and get to what you need through that instead.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should not need to access `HttpContext.Current` directly. You should be able to use one of the **[available dependencies](https://github.com/openrasta/openrasta/wiki/Available-Dependencies)** which are easily mockable.